# How to change sha256 text infinitely(or maybe a bunch of times)

Tags: python, python-3.x

````
 ``` sha256("ABC".encode("ascii")).hexdigest()

def SHA256(text):
  return sha256(text.encode("ascii")).hexdigest()


MAX_NONCE=100000000        ># You can also use a while loop to run infinitely with no 
upper limit
def mine(block_number,transaction,previous_hash,prefix_zeros):
  prefix_str='0'*prefix_zeros
  for nonce in range(MAX_NONCE):
    text= str(block_number) + transaction + previous_hash + str(nonce)
    hash = SHA256(text)
    ># print(hash)
    if hash.startswith(prefix_str):
      print("Bitcoin mined with nonce value :",nonce)
      return hash
  print("Could not find a hash in the given range of upto", MAX_NONCE) ```
````

i want the hash to change and then print it out like 1k times after another(it needs to change every time)

Comment: What's your specific question?

Comment: Does that not work? Your nonce is always just a number but should still give you different sha256's

Comment: SHA-256 has been designed to avoid collisions, so as long as it is not broken, **any** message you feed it results in a different hash, you only should try and avoid duplicate messages.

Answer (score 0):

check out generators, iterators, and the yield keyword. Here is something from [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/use-yield-keyword-instead-return-keyword-python/)

just like how range can be 1,000 numbers, or an infinite sequence, we can do the same kind of thing

```
import random

def dice_roller(sides=6):
    while True:
        yield int(random.random() * sides)


dice_rolls = dice_roller()

for roll in dice_rolls:
    if roll == 1:
        break
    
    print(roll)
```

execute that at your own risk. I tried to add the break to keep it from rolling off into infinity